# Reading signature changed serializable object from file

Tags: java, android, serialization, android-file

I have a `Serializable` class named `SimpleClass` with it's attributes and methods. I'm using following code to write and read its object to/from file.

Saving (w/o exception handling code):

```
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
os.writeObject(simpleClass);
os.close();
fos.close();
```

Loading (w/o exception handling code):

```
FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(fileName);
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
SimpleClass simpleClass = (SimpleClass) is.readObject();
is.close();
fis.close();
```

After a while, I added a getter method to it(only the method, not attribute). 
After this, `SimpleClass simpleClass = (SimpleClass) is.readObject();` fails. The file is there and I assume that the addition of method caused this.
ie, object that saved inside file is not same as the object that I have now.
Is there any workaround on this? How can I read the old object without removing the additional method?

Comment: Have you used a serialversionUID for your SimpleClass

Answer (score 0):

Define a `long` value for **serialVersionUID** in **SimpleClass.java** .I assume you can edit the class.

```
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

make it a unique id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the `serialver` tool on the class as it was before the change, and add the resulting `serialVersionUID` value to the class as it is now.